# Where should I ask for help in using Open Office?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I'm trying to use OpenOffice to create my resume, and I'd like to turn a png into a bullet point graphic. How do I do that, and where is a more appropriate place to ask questions like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about
>
> - computer software